# Can app open browser, get user to login and receive file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url

I'm trying to write an iOS Objective-C app to login to an old website. Note I don't have control of the website so I have no way of changing the login.

The procedure is:

1. Open browser at specific URL.
2. User enters their username and password.
3. Website returns a file called something like bad_link.smith.
4. App reads file to get key to use for API.

Is it possible to do this in iOS - open a URL from an app and have the file returned?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UIWebView` Delegates for this

Implement this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: delegate method and get the URL the user is going to and if the URL matches the URL you want to download then you can get the URL by the NSURLRequest and download it seperately. :) Hope I helped you.

What other thing you could do is make the code native and without the browser and simulating as a browser in the code. Can be used if no CAPTCHA is there. Do tell if you need more info on this.

Comment: What JSON? I'm trying to receive a file.

Comment: @parsley72 Sorry I mixed up two answers :P. I updated my answer, see if you need any more details.